# Forward differencing (and back)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, numerical-methods, interpolation, finite-differences

I read that "forward differencing" is a method for "evaluating polynomials at uniformly spaced intervals". That is, if I have parabola like $y = x^2$ and increase $x$ by 1, I can use it.

My question is, does it also work "backwards"? If I want uniformly spaced $y$ values (say by 1 as well), is it somehow possible to use it? How do I choose the "differences" so that the output is regularly spaced?

Comment: **Hint:** use `$` to start a math formula and close it with other `$`, instead of `.